How to UpdateRecords from UIAPI using UpdateRecords from LWC Array
How to update from updateRecord UIAPI in lWC for List of Arrays
I have a lwc component which returns an Array of idString and i would need to pass it to parameter for listofRecords which would check for all the elements and update the name value to us account and update in bulk
can't use apex because of performance and server calls need to use lwc updaterRecord but it's not updating the record
Is there any approach wrong in my code

const COLS = [
    {label:'Id', fieldName:'Id'},
    {label:'name', fieldName:'name'},
];

idString =["1234","4567","7890","2345"];

  updateContactRecordus(listOfrecords) {
        let promises = [];
        listOfrecords.forEach(idsString => {
            let fields = {
                Name: 'US Account'
            };
            console.log('Value of fields is'+ fields);

            promises.push(updateRecord({ fields }));
        });
        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(result => {
            this.showToast('Success', 'Records updated successfully', 'success');
            // Optionally, handle any post-update logic here
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.showToast('Error updating records', error.body.message, 'error');
        });
}

showToast(title, message, variant) {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: title,
        message: message,
        variant: variant
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}


You need to include the field: Id in your fields object

Adding  a id field as well still the values are not updated

What do you mean "can't use apex because of performance"? What's the performance issue you're trying to avoid?

We are trying to avoid server calls and make use the client side caching

But why? what's wrong with server calls?  Wouldn't a single server call with an array of records be better than individually calling the updateRecord api?  This sounds a lot like premature optimisation to me.

Instead of calling updateRecord in a for loop, use Promise.all. In the new lwc recipes for lightning-datatable you can find some examples. Look at this one.
